# Getting coin prices from pancakeswap using different LP's (BUSD, USDT)

Tags: javascript, bsc, pancakeswap

Trying to obtain coin prices on the BSC with pancakefactory2 using other LPs besides BNB(BUSD, USDT). Right now this is my code and the prices its getting is off by 5-15%. Any ideas on whats wrong?

```
   * @param symbol {string}
   * @return {Promise<void>}
   */
  async getLatestPrice (symbol) {
    if (!this.symbolContracts.has(symbol)) {
      return null
    }
    const reservesResultsA = await this.batchCalls(
      this.symbolContracts.get(symbol).contractPairsA.map(
        (cp) => ({call: cp.methods.getReserves(), contract: cp})),
    )
    const pairPriceA = this.getAveragedPriceFromReserves(reservesResultsA)

    if (this.symbolLpMap.get(symbol) === LPS.Lp.USDT ||
      this.symbolLpMap.get(symbol) === LPS.Lp.BUSD
    ) {
      // number is still a whole number, apply the proper decimal places from the contract
      return pairPriceA.dividedBy(Math.pow(10, this.getDecimals(symbol)))
    }
    else {
      const reservesResultsB = await this.batchCalls(
        this.symbolContracts.get(symbol).contractPairsB.map(
          (cp) => ({call: cp.methods.getReserves(), contract: cp})),
      )

      const pairPriceB = this.getAveragedPriceFromReserves(reservesResultsB)

      // Multiply pair A by pair B to get the USD value
      let price = pairPriceA.multipliedBy(pairPriceB)

      // number is still a whole number, apply the proper decimal places from the contract
      return price.dividedBy(Math.pow(10, this.getDecimals(symbol)))
    }
  }
}
```

These are the BSC addresses of the tokens im using.

```
// ADDRESSES
const PANCAKESWAP_FACTORY_ADDR_V2 = '0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73'
const ADDRESS_BNB = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c'
const ADDRESS_BUSD = '0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56'
const ADDRESS_USDT = '0x524bc91dc82d6b90ef29f76a3ecaabafffd490bc'
```

````
getAveragedPriceFromReserves = function (callContractAndResultList) {
    const reserve0 = callContractAndResultList.reduce(
      (a, b) => a.plus(new BigNumber(
        b.result[b.contract.addressOrderReversed ? '1' : '0'])),
      new BigNumber(0),
    )
    const reserve1 = callContractAndResultList.reduce(
      (a, b) => a.plus(new BigNumber(
        b.result[b.contract.addressOrderReversed ? '0' : '1'])),
      new BigNumber(0),
    )
    return reserve1.dividedBy(reserve0)
  }```
````

Comment: What does `getAveragedPriceFromReserves` do?

Comment: getAveragedPriceFromReserves is reserve1/reserve0. However, sometimes I want to take the average of all of the pairs in the event there are multiple liquidity pools. This helps in those cases. I edited the original post and put the code at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `reserve0` and `reserve1` have a different floating point precision.

Since they're stored as `uint256` (integers), ERC20 stores the number of decimals each token uses and you need to convert them into real numbers before dividing them.

```
p0 = (reserve1/10**decimals1) / (reserve0/10**decimals0)
```

For instance, USDC has a precision of 6 decimals and WETH uses 18. So if pool has 1 WETH and 3000 USDC, `reserve0 = 1000000000000000000` and `reserve1 = 3000000000`.

With your code, 1 WETH = 3000000000 / 1000000000000000000 = 0.000000003 USDC.

If corrected, 1 WETH = 3000 / 1 = 3000 USDC.

Also, to reduce (sum) all values, you need to first convert them into a real number, then add them up.

Comment: Sorry it took so long for me to get back to you. Thank you, it worked!

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer then :)